# How do I prevent an attribute on a property of a parent class from being applied to that property in the child?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a parent class, `ListableEntity`, whose `Description` property is using an attribute `[DbUnique]`, which places a unique constraint on this field in the SQL table.

```
public abstract partial class ParentEntity<T> {

    [DbUnique]
    public string Description { get; protected set; }
}
```

I need to create a child class of ListableEntity which, unlike the parent, is permitted to have duplicates values for the `Description` property.  But even when I hide the parent attribute in my child class, this DbUnique attribute is still being applied somehow, preventing duplicate Descriptions.  Here's the relevant excerpt of what I have for the child class:

```
public class ChildEntity : ParentEntity<ChildEntity>
{
    public new string Description { get; private set; }
}
```

I'm very new to C#.  My understanding was that this child's Description property would overwrite the parent's for ChildEntity objects, but when trying to save ChildEntities with duplicate descriptions, I'm still getting the exception, "Cannot insert duplicate key row with unique index 'IX_Description'."  Does anyone know why this attribute from the parent property is still getting applied, and how I can prevent this?  Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be violating Lusocf Substitution Principle, and you're fighting the effects. EF likely was designed not to violate LSP so if you find a solution it'll likely be hacky.

Comment: @NexTerren Not really - since hiding is not overriding you can substitute parent with child without any impact (confusing for user of Child class, but not a violation of LSP). The problem OP is facing is likely not related to code show, but to the fact that DB is generated based on parent's info and no manipulation with child classes would remove uniqueness constraint from the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do two things, one is to change the properties names, for example ParentDescription and ChildDescription (I think that this is the best option). The other is to have one more class with the atribute "Description" as "abstract", so in the child classes you have to override those atributes.

GrandParent -> ParentEntity -> ChildEntity